# LinkedIn windows phone oauth2 without uri

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone, uri, linkedin-api

I want that my Windows Phone 8 app uses LinkedIn in order to search companies and get contacts. To do so I need an Access Token and, to get that, I need an Authorization Code.

As far as I have read, the LinkedIn API uses OAUTH2 and the url to get the Authorization Code is the following:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
&scope=SCOPE
&state=STATE
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

The problem is the REDIRECT URI parameter. I don't want that, because I just want to get the Authorization Code, and then get the Token with the code.

Do you know if is there any way to avoid redirecting? Or using some kind of redirect which doesn't bring you to other webpage?

Comment: You need to have some redirect URI. The perfect way would be to open the URL in the IE and make your app listen to your own protocol handler, like `yourapp://oauth` and then you can get the OAuth token from its GET param.

Comment: I think that the redirect URI only admits http, https and ftp. I have read it somewhere

Comment: If so, you can use any URL (should be your server since the owner could read the OAuth token as well) and then you can look in the browser control's OnNavigated event for each called URI, whether it has the OAuth token in the URL. There's no other way besides the 2 mentioned.

Comment: Is possible using localhost ?

Comment: Why don't you simply host an empty website on Heroku or so, and use that one? It could work with localhost, but I don't know whether the occurring 404 not found error will harm your app experience. It could lead to problems, I guess.

Comment: I decided to use a custom host, as you said. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a custom host, so now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar issue, I struggled with this and found an easier way (maybe not the correct way). 
I redirected to a made up address (http://madeupaddress.com) and on the Navigating event checked if the url started with my made up address, if so, i closed the browser and take the token from the e.URI.Query parameters, then apply for the access token using the code.

Thanks go to [Vittorio Bertocci](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/16/a-sample-windows-phone-8-app-getting-tokens-from-windows-azure-ad-and-adfs/#comment-156665)